# Using two different databases in a SQL Query in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, ssis

I'm using MongoDB as a new source of information and I'm facing a problem that I can't quite fix without rebuilding the data flows with every change like a new column made in MongoDB.

For example, normally you can map the columns and when a new column is added in the source you can just add it in the mapping and everything is fine. Like this:

SQL Source mapping:

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
3 -> 3
```

MongoDB Source mapping: At first works the same as a SQL source. But when theres a column added (2a) in MongoDB it works as follows:

```
1 ->  1
2a -> 2
2 ->  3
3 ->  4
```

Even though I've changed the mapping to the correct columns.

My solution would be something like using a pre-staging table where the complete table is copied from Mongo to a SQL table and then use the pre-staging table as a source where the mapping should work.

The problem I'm facing right now is that I need to use two database servers on different servers. The query should look something like this:

```
SELECT *
INTO (Server2.Destination)
FROM (Server1.Source)
```

Anyone has faced this problem and had a solution?

Comment: It is a little ambiguous how you refer to `SQL` above. I assume from the context and the fact that you've tagged `sql-server` that you mean `MSSQL` as opposed to the generic `SQL` language, but it might be advisable to edit your post and clarify that.